# Issues Debugging MVVM Bindings in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mvvm-light

I'm developing an application in Visual Studio using MVVM Light and Ninject. Unfortunately, when I try to debug this application and there's a problem in one of my ViewModels, instead of actually debugging the code, I get something like this:

[image: Example Debug Image]

This is rather useless and impossible to debug. Now, if I know where the error is or have an idea, I can insert breakpoints there in the code and Visual Studio will show the correct info, but I don't always know where the error is. I can't just breakpoint every line of code in the application. Is there a way to force Visual Studio to look past the UI and debug the actual code?

Comment: Also, yes, there's a version number in the project name. I know it's laughably bad and needs to be corrected.

Comment: You could try writing unit tests. You should fix your XAML though.

Comment: What's wrong in the XAML?

Comment: It's complaining about the `Owner` property. What is `Auto_Calibrator_v0._05.MainWindow`? In general, main windows don't have an owner. Not sure what your design is, but I don't think you need to set that property.

Comment: Hard to tell with the tiny peek at your MVVM application you've given. See the possible exceptions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) for Window.Owner and go from there.

Comment: Oh! Wrong exception. Forgive me, I uploaded the wrong screenshot. I'll change it.

Comment: That is standard behavior for exceptions that occur because of values you set in XAML. There is no code there to show really, that's the code right there. Well strictly speaking there is code _generated_ from the XAML but it's well hidden and won't be usually shown not even in the debugger. And yes, don't set the Owner property.

Comment: Essentially it skips past code in the ViewModels. If there's an exception it just shows it in the XAML instead. I'd like the debugger to debug the code in the ViewModels instead of skipping over it. I can't find a way to do this without breakpointing everything.

Comment: @AlexPaven There is code because there are bindings. It should debug the code behind these bindings in the ViewModel or it's a failure as a debugger.

Comment: @AlexPaven And it can debug this code if I breakpoint it. I just can't always know what to breakpoint if there's a tricky error.

Comment: Well what sort of error? I'm afraid I never ran into anything similar, and I've done my fair share of WPF... Exceptions will break at the closest point to where they're occurring that's user code, and I suppose there are plenty of XAML-related exceptions that could behave like that, but...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to set the owner of the application main window.

The correct way to set the owner of a window in XAML is as follows

```
<object>
  <object.Owner>
    <Window .../>
  </object.Owner>
</object>
```

alternatively you can set it from code behind like this

```
// Create a window and make this window its owner
Window ownedWindow = new Window();
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.Show();
```

The way you have done WPF tries to convert the string "Auto_Calibrator_v0._05.MainWindow" to window object which is not possible unless you have a type converter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to view the error please make it large or type it in text format.
This is from my page.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Retail.View.Settings.ShopSetting"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"      `      
             DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ShopSettingVM}"
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:RetailPOS.View.Usercontrols.Settings"
             xmlns:Utility="clr-namespace:RetailPOS.Utility" xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
             xmlns:Toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit">
```

Match this may be it can help
Thanks